# org-mode - hiding blank lines when cycling plain lists

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have noticed that trailing blank lines only get folded under headings but not under plain lists. For example:

```
* Heading 1

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...

* Heading 2
* Heading 3
```

when cycled, is folded to:

```
* Heading 1...
* Heading 2...
* Heading 3
```

But when this plain list is folded:

```
- List item 1

  Some text goes here

- List item 2
- List item 3
```

I get this:

```
- List item 1...

- List item 2...
- List item 3
```

In order to get rid of the extra blank space, I have been writing my plain lists like this:

```
- List item 1

  Some text goes here
- List item 2
- List item 3
```

which is visually annoying.

Is there a variable I can set to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a variable to influence this. This happens in org-cycle-internal-local when it calculates eos by calling org-list-get-item-end-before-blank and, as the name implies, this does not include the blank line at the end of the item.

You would have to replace that call with a call to org-list-get-item-end to do what you want (I think - untested). You might try asking for the feature on the orgmode mailing list.